# How to reverse the order of rows for vlooking bottom up?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So basically I setup a whole bunch of cells to vlookup another spreadsheet, and I realize in hindsight the ranges can change on this other spreadsheet, so to solve this problem I want to vlookup bottom up since the "totals" category and all of its sub categories will always be on the bottom.

Current situation:

Register 1:

Cash: $10    <---- if the number of "registers" changes it will push the wrong values into my vlookup range.

Register 2:

Cash $30

Total

Cash: $40   <--- I want to vlookup that total "cash".

Here's an example of the one of the current vlookups I have in the master:
=iferror(vlookup("Cash",IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/File_ID","Burger Place!A21:K40"),4,false),)

So I build these sheets the master references from excel sheets, so I was thinking I can just include a sort command at the end to reverse the order when they're created, or I can just integrate something into the vlookup... to be honest I don't know what to do. I'm new with google script any any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If without vlookup you can get data like this:

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA({row(B25:B28), left(B25:B28,4), B25:B28}),"select Col3 where Col2=""cash"" order by Col1 Desc limit 1")
```

You can change B25:B28 to

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/File_ID","Burger Place!A21:K40")
```

And change Select Col3 to

```
select Col7
```

If you will used vlookup:

```
=vlookup("Cash",query(arrayformula({row(A21:A),A21:A,D21:D}),"Select Col2, Col3 where Col2=""Cash"" order by Col1 Desc"),2,false)
```

With assumption, A21:A, D21:D are from import range, and "Cash" in Column A without any suffix, just "Cash" and column D is value to find